# Uploaded files not appearing in Github

Tags: php, laravel, github, laravel-forge

I am having a really strange problem. I'll try keep it simple.

I am developing a web app using Laravel and it involves allowing users to upload and download files. I have created a function that allows a user to upload a file. This works grand. I can login to my site from another computer and see that the file was uploaded, and I can download it. So it seems to be working grand.

However, the file that I have uploaded is not appearing in the folder which it is supposed to on GitHub. This is really strange because the file definitely is there...because I can download it from another computer.

Code for uploading the file.

```
$destinationPath = public_path().'/files/';
$file->move($destinationPath, $file->getClientOriginalName());
```

I cannot see why the file I have uploaded isn't appearing on Git seeing as it has definitely uploaded.

Any ideas?

Comment: GitHub != server. It will only get the files you tell the GitHub client to put there.

Comment: Uploading a file to your server doesn't make that file magically become part of your repository, nor does it execute a `git push` to sync the repository up to Github.

Answer (score 2):

The files that you are looking for are located on your server.  Adding or removing files from the server does not add or remove them from your git repository.  In order to add them to your git repository, you would need to run the git commands to do so.  The commands depend on what exactly you want to add, but as a general example:

To add all files

```
git add -A
```

Followed with a commit

```
git commit -m "example commit"
```

They will not appear on GitHub until you push

```
git push origin branch-name
```

Answer (score 0):

For Git you have to manually commit the files.
Go to your command line and run

```
git status
```

If it shows public/ files then you would need to manually add them.

```
git add public
```

If they're not showing there, they're either being ignored or they've been committed and possibly not pushed.

Answer (score -2):

First thing inside your project folder if the `.git` folder is created, delete it. Then write this series of code
commands:

```
git config --global user.name   "your name"
git config --global user.email "your email"
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git status
git remote add origin   # paste here ssh link from github repository
git push origin master
```

Comment: This does not appear to add anything over the existing answers from several years ago. The suggestion to remove the `.git` folder is actively harmful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at your .gitignore file. It might be the case that you instruct Git there to ignore the file.

Comment: Also, if it's a production server, it may not be pushing to GitHub. It may only be pulling.

Comment: Where are my files going if they are not being uploaded to GitHub. Where can I locate and view the files? The files are definitely somewhere because like I said, I can download and view them. I am fairly new to this. I am using Laravel Forge, a Linode Server and GitHub to give you a better idea of what I am asking.